# PyQt: Overriding QGraphicsView.drawItems

Tags: python, pyqt

I need to customize the drawing process of a QGraphicsView, and so I override the drawItems method like this:

```
self.graphicsview.drawItems=self.drawer.drawItems
```

where `self.graphicsview` is a QGraphicsView, and `self.drawer` is a custom class with a method `drawItems`.
In this method I check a few flags to decide how to draw each item, and then call `item.paint`, like this:

```
def drawItems(self, painter, items, options):
    for item in items:
        print "Processing", item
        # ... Do checking ...
        item.paint(painter, options, self.target)
```

`self.target` is the QGraphicsView's QGraphicsScene.
However, once it reaches `item.paint`, it breaks out of the loop - without any errors. If I put conditionals around the painting, and for each possible type of QGraphicsItem paste the code that is supposed to be executed (by looking at the Qt git-sources), everything works.
Not a very nice solution though... And I don't understand how it could even break out of the loop?

Comment: Just tried adding this statement, `print item.paint`, to verify which paint method would be invoked. It printed "<built-in method paint of QGraphicsPixmapItem object at 0x02295588>". Built-in? I also have a custom object derived from QGraphicsItem, and above statement gives "bound method of ..." instead.  
What does this difference mean?

Comment: "built-in" means that compiled code in the Qt library is called while "bound method" means that Python code is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an exception that occurs when the items are painted, but it is not reported right away. On my system (PyQt 4.5.1, Python 2.6), no exception is reported when I monkey-patch the following method:

```
def drawItems(painter, items, options):
    print len(items)
    for idx, i in enumerate(items):
        print idx, i
        if idx > 5:
            raise ValueError()
```

Output:

```
45
0 <PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsPathItem object at 0x3585270>
1 <PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem object at 0x356ca68>
2 <PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem object at 0x356ce20>
3 <PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem object at 0x356cc88>
4 <PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem object at 0x356cc00>
5 <PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem object at 0x356caf0>
6 <PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem object at 0x356cb78>
```

However, once I close the application, the following method is printed:

```
Exception ValueError: ValueError() in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

I tried printing `threading.currentThread()`, but it returns the same thread whether it's called in- or outside the monkey-patched `drawItems` method.

In your code, this is likely due to the fact that you pass `options` (which is a list of style options objects) to the individual items rather than the respective option object. Using this code should give you the correct results:

```
def drawItems(self, painter, items, options):
    for item, option in zip(items, options):
        print "Processing", item
        # ... Do checking ...
        item.paint(painter, option, self.target)
```

Also, you say the `self.target` is the scene object. The [documentation for `paint()`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qgraphicsitem.html#paint) says:

> This function, which is usually called by QGraphicsView, paints the contents of an item in local coordinates. ... The widget argument is optional. If provided, it points to the widget that is being painted on; otherwise, it is 0. For cached painting, widget is always 0.

and the type is `QWidget*`. `QGraphicsScene` inherits from `QObject` and is not a widget, so it is likely that this is wrong, too.

Still, the fact that the exception is not reported at all, or not right away suggests some foul play, you should contact the maintainer.

Comment: Hm. I don't get that threading error. However, I get "argument 2 of QGraphicsPolygonItem.paint() has an invalid type". Argument 2 is the option-parameter, which is passed unchanged.  
Doing `type(options)` tells me it is a standard Python list - so it is down-cast, but cannot be "up-cast" again. This must be a bug in the wrappers?

Comment: Just re-read the docs and played around a bit and realized the same thing (re the list of options). Thanks for your help!
It's wierd that the exception does not seem to surface unless I surround it with a try/except though...

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the loop suddenly exits is that an Exception is thrown. Python doesn't handle it (there is no `try:` block), so it's passed to the called (Qt's C++ code) which has no idea about Python exceptions, so it's lost.

Add a try/except around the loop and you should see the reason why this happens.

Note: Since Python 2.4, you should not override methods this way anymore.

Instead, you must derive a new class from QGraphicsView and add your `drawItems()` method to this new class. This will replace the original method properly.

Don't forget to call `super()` in the `__init__` method! Otherwise, your object won't work properly.

Comment: But... My overriding method is called properly?

Comment: That's more by chance than by intention.

Comment: Well, it only works if you call it on an instance. If you try things like that on a class, it fails.

Comment: But he does it to an instance, which is more or less the idea of monkey-patching.